# what is the difference between 合う and 正しい？

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I know that both can mean "correct". I frequently hear things like "合ってる？" to mean :"is it right?" I don't know much about the use of 正しい, but I know that it's also a common word for "correct".

What would be the difference between the two? Is there a preference for one over the other in certain situations and formality levels?

Comment: あってる in this context is spelt 合ってる.

Comment: Fixed 会う to  合 う.

Answer (score 5):

I understand your question is "what is the difference between 合う and 正しい？" as is said by Aeon Akechi.

**合う** means basically **A is equal to B** or **A and B are equal**. So if it is used like "あなたの答｛こた｝えは合っている", the phrase means "your answer is equal to the correct answer".
On the other hand **正しい** means basically "**right**" along with the meaning of "**correct**".

So, 正 in 正しい is used in both ways.
For example, 正解{せいかい} means a correct answer, while 正義｛せいぎ｝ means justice, right or righteousness.

Answer (score 0):

合う is a verb, 正しい is an adjective.

I've seen 合う's primary use as an intransitive verb with the meaning of "to fit" or "to match".

Examples: その洋服は彼女の赤い髪に合う。(That dress matches her red hair.)
このジャケットはぴったり合う。(This jacket sets well.)

正しい's use as an i-adjective is a little different.
私の意見は大抵において正しい。(My opinion is generally correct.)
厳密に言うと、君は正しくない。(Strictly speaking, you're not correct.)