# Grammar / translation trouble with 合ってる

Tags: grammar

I am having trouble fully understanding a sentence from an anime I am watching at the moment.

この先フェルトって子の家で合ってる？

Specifically 合ってる used in this context is confusing for me.

Comment: Are you sure that 子の家 is correct? Can you provide more context?

Comment: @kandyman I don't think that part is likely to be a typo.

Comment: Does this answer you? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51815/7810

Comment: @kandyman It’s (フェルトって子)の家, which is perfectly fine

Comment: understood, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese is a very context-dependent language, so individual sentences can be hard to decode.

Without more context, it looks like it's:

"After this it's the house of the kid/girl named {feruto}, right?"

何々で合ってる？ is a way of confirming information, roughly equivalent to "... right?"